# lyx url.sty missing

Tags: lyx

New installation of full Lyx package.
Inserted a hyperlink in paper and I am getting the following error.
Any solutions suggested, I've tried inserting a couple insert package solutions and none have worked, not sure why lyx isn't finding this file.
[image]

Comment: You need to install the `url` package in your TeX distribution. If you're using MikTeX for example, use the Package manager you find in the start menu.

Comment: Following the [LyX wiki on installation](http://wiki.lyx.org/Windows/WindowsSetup), you need to install a TeX distribution *before* you install LyX (since LyX will prompt you during installation about the location of the installed TeX distribution). What distribution did you use? I'm guessing it's MiKTeX which allows you to install complete but minimal components. See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)

Comment: thanks, i used the miktex package manager and installed the url package and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

Installing [`url` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/url) [via the package manager](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169374/lyx-url-sty-missing#comment389724_169374) worked.

Comment: As it stands, this seems more appropriate as a comment, too, rather than an answer. Could you please explain how one actually would install the `url` package via the MikTeX package manager, otherwise this should really just be a comment.