# Missing packages - Package Manager doesn't work

Tags: packages, miktex, installing, texstudio

I just installed TeXstudio in my computer (I'm running Windows 7) and installed MiKTeX as well. I wrote a file and when I try to compile it messages like `File 'cite.sty' not found. \usepackage` or `File 'url.sty' not found. \usepackage` appear.

I tried using the Package Manager as stated [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169374/lyx-url-sty-missing) but when I try to do that, with any package, a message appears saying that it couldn't connect to the server.

Isn't there another way to install these packages without using the package manager? I've downloaded the file `cite.sty` from [here](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cite/) and saved it in the folder where all the other packages are, but it is still not compiling. Any ideas?

Comment: if you are saving cite.sty by hand save it to the folder with the document, adding it to the folders managed by the package manager will just confuse it or you or both:-)

Comment: Well, it's really the simplest way. Did you launch MPM as administrator or as user?

Comment: @Bernard I've launched it as User, I'm using a computer from my work so I don't have administrator permissions. Should I ask for them? Isn't it possible to install them without being admin?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, putting the files in the document folder worked! It's not the most classy way to do it, but it's good enough for me. Write it as an answer if you want so I can accept it.

Comment: @Tendero must be a duplicate, I'll see...

Comment: If you have only a few packages to install, you can download; say, `url.tar.lzma` from a MiKTeX directory on a CTAN mirror, and unzip it at the root of MiKTeX directory (usually `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\``for the 64 bit version). Then launch `MiKTeX Settings` and refresh the FNDB. If you install type1  fonts, in addition, you also have to run `updmap.exe` from the command line.

Comment: The following can do miracles (sometimes): Maintenance>settings>Refresh FNDB. I dont know, if it helps, but it is often good for a first try.

Comment: Since you are using MikTeX from work there might be a problem with proxy server configuration. If your organization uses a proxy server you should configure it appropriately in the settings of the package manager. In order to do so go to the menu item "Repository" --> "Change Package Repository" --> "Connection Settings" and enable the usage of the proxy server.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main points to consider when installing a package manually (which you should *ideally* do with administrative privileges, because it's MikTeX):

- Never use the automatically generated file tree. This is just because you normally don't want your packages to be modified by a (potentially not working) package manager. Install it to any **other folder** and add it as TeX root (via MikTeX Settings).
- After doing so you have to **refresh the filename database** (FNDB) and maybe also to update formats. That's done via the MikTeX Settings.

If you just need the files for one project, it is mostyle also enough to just copy them to that directory.